# Toggle a particular class on clicking a button

Tags: c#, jquery

i have a class named "box" and "box box-collapsed" and on clicking a thing they should toggle its working fine but there are other elements with same class so they are also being effected.

```
 <script>
 $(".box-collapse").click(function () {
    $(".box").toggleClass("box box-collapsed");
  });
</script>
```

So is there any way that that particular class will be effected

Comment: Can you show your sample HTML?

Comment: did you tryed $(this).toggleClass() ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you're after. But if I'm not mistaken, you want to push a button with the class `box-collapse`, on clicking this you switch another element from `box` to `box-collapsed` and vica versa.

I'm assuming here you also have multiple `box-collapse` buttons, one for each `box` you want to collapse. Ohterwise I wouldn't really know how you would target your `box`.

If you put your `box-collapse` button just before the collapsable box, you can use `$(this)` as selector, and target the next element.

```
 $(".box-collapse").click(function () {
$(this).next().toggleClass("box box-collapsed");
});
```

If you'd share your HTML we can give a more detailled answer.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GH2z6/3/